# Unity UIElements ListView expand

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm write Unity editor inspector extension and use ListView. How can i expand ListView height to bottom of Inspector window?[Inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf6C2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the style property that is present with the ListView to flex the container for sure.

of listview.style look into the options and maybe we can have the flexbox to floating might help